# How can I deploy a dynamic React-app on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, buildpack, procfile

I've been attempting to deploy a react-app in Heroku for a while now, and every tip on the internet tells me to use [Buildpack for create-react-app](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack), but that build pack is now outdated and no longer supports the heroku-22 stack.

I attempted to deploy the app using the node-js-buildpack, but was unable to do so. My Heroku procfile has the following command: `web: npm install -g serve && serve -s build`, however as you can see, it only delivers a static version, not a dynamic one.

The package.json react scripts I have are this ones:
`"scripts": { "start": "react-scripts start", "build": "react-scripts build", "test": "react-scripts test", "eject": "react-scripts eject" },`

The npm serve instructions allow me to access the website, but unlike my localhost one, it does not display the updated data when fresh data is received. In addition, in my development version, I use yarn as a package manager.

The app runs like so:

1. I have some PostgreSQL triggers that inform me when data is insert or
   edited on specific tables, and then I supply the API server with the
   table name that was changed.
2. I get it on my node-js API server, which also serves as a web-socket server, and I send the name of the table that was changed to the
   client over a channel.
3. So, depending on which table has been modified, my react-js client
   re-fetches the updated information.

The client has connection to the web-socket as appears on the network tab of the developer tools for browsers.

Comment: _"it only delivers a static version, not a dynamic one"_ - that's what's _supposed_ to happen in production. Hot reloading is for when you're editing the files in development, so you can immediately see what's changed, your end users won't be able to change the files on Heroku.

Comment: I understand the misunderstanding; I did not say the correct words. What I meant was that when new data is received, such as on my localhost, it does not display the updated data.

Comment: What do you mean _"new data is received"_? By what? From where? You're writing a single-page app, that's just static content - the dev server is only for local development. Even if you _tried_ to save things to the dyno, it's an ephemeral environment that restarts at least daily (https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted-from-the-application).

Comment: Currently, I have some PostgreSQL triggers that notify me when data is inserted or modified on particular tables, and then I provide the client the name of the table that was altered and then re-fetch that data to receive the information. It's not a one-page app; it includes several views, including a dashboard.

Comment: It's really not at all clear how your system works - _"notify"_ and _"provide"_ how? Please [edit] to give a [mre]. And note a single-page app doesn't mean it has only one view, it's about where the rendering to HTML takes place (client-side vs. server-side) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA.

Comment: My post has been updated to properly describe how my app works. Also, thank you for clarifying the distinction and providing the reference.

Comment: There's no reason what you describe couldn't work with the bundled React app's files being served statically. It's still running in your users' browsers, and can still connect to the websocket and update the view accordingly. It's not entirely clear what problem you have. Again please give a MRE, something people can _run_ to reproduce the problem. Do some debugging, see if build then serve works locally, make sure any e.g. proxy settings actually reflect the production environment.